# Setting "width: auto" inside a <div> with "display: flex; flex-direction: row" doesn't work

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to place bunch of divs side by side, left to right. So I'm using a flexbox with direction set to `row`.

I want each of those divs to derive their height and width from the content inside, hence I have left their height and width to default.

Lastly, I want to use an svg as the background. For that, I'm using a grid container and placing both the svg and the div in the same column and row as suggested in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51949049/9613633). Im setting the height and width of the svg to `100%` to ensure it fills the whole background.

When I combine everything together, though, the width is of the divs are not being set properly. The height of the div seems to be set by the content inside, but the width seems to always default to `300px`. For the life of me, I cant figure out how this width is being calculated. If the content is wider than `300px`, then everything works as expected. But the container never shrinks to fit if the content is smaller than `300px`.

How can I makes sure the divs are always shrunk to fit? See the code sample below:

```css
.top {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grid-container {
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
}

.svg {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
This div has calculated width 300px for some reason
<div class="top">
  <div class="grid-container" key="1">
    <svg class="svg" viewBox="-10 -10 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <polygon strokeWidth="0" fill="yellow" points="0,-10 10,0 0,10 -10,0" />
    </svg>
    <div class="content">
      ab
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- more grid-containers -->
</div>

This works as expected
<div class="top">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <svg class="svg" viewBox="-10 -10 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <polygon strokeWidth="0" fill="yellow" points="0,-10 10,0 0,10 -10,0" />
    </svg>
    <div class="content">
      abcdefghijkl
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- more grid-containers -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default width/height applied to SVG element creating this output. To avoid the issue make sure you set the **attribute** width/height to 0

```css
.top {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grid-container {
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
}

.svg {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
This div has calculated width 300px for some reason
<div class="top">
  <div class="grid-container" key="1">
    <svg class="svg" viewBox="-10 -10 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="0" height="0">
      <polygon strokeWidth="0" fill="yellow" points="0,-10 10,0 0,10 -10,0" />
    </svg>
    <div class="content">
      ab
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- more grid-containers -->
</div>

This works as expected
<div class="top">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <svg class="svg" viewBox="-10 -10 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="0" height="0">
      <polygon strokeWidth="0" fill="yellow" points="0,-10 10,0 0,10 -10,0" />
    </svg>
    <div class="content">
      abcdefghijkl
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- more grid-containers -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I found in this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/width) that the svg width is supposed to be set to `300px` only if both `viewBox` and `width` attributes are unset, but that doesn't seem to be the case. The width gets set to `300px` even when `viewBox` is set.

Comment: @Cnoor0171 you are correct. My answer wasn't very accurate but I was refering to intrinsic dimension created by the viewBox. First, you will notice that Firefox gives a complete different output for your code than chrome and you will not see the 300px of width but something else. I don't know exactly what browser is doing wrong also Flexbox and CSS grid make the caclulation more complex ... but at the end I knew that setting width/height to 0 would fix the issue. I will probably update later if I find a better explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by adding `position: relative;` to the `.grid-container` and `position: absolute;` to the `svg` and then giving the `.content` a `z-index:1;`

See here:

```css
.top {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grid-container {
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.svg {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  font-size: 100px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
This div has calculated width 300px for some reason
<div class="top">
  <div class="grid-container" key="1">
    <svg class="svg" viewBox="-10 -10 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <polygon id="diamond" strokeWidth="0" fill="yellow" points="0,-10 10,0 0,10 -10,0" />
    </svg>
    <div class="content">
      ab
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- more grid-containers -->
</div>

This works as expected
<div class="top">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <svg class="svg" viewBox="-10 -10 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <polygon strokeWidth="0" fill="yellow" points="0,-10 10,0 0,10 -10,0" />
    </svg>
    <div class="content">
      abcdefghijkl
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- more grid-containers -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use SVG as background image for the `.grid-container` (inline or linked), so you won't need to insert it into **each single** div. **Importantly**, the SVG must have `preserveAspectRatio = 'none'`:

```css
.top {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grid-container {
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  background-image: 
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='-10 -10 20 20' preserveAspectRatio='none'> <polygon strokeWidth='0' fill='yellow' points='0,-10 10,0 0,10 -10,0'/> </svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="grid-container" key="1">
    <div class="content">
      ab
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- more grid-containers -->
</div>

<div class="top">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="content">
      abcdefghijkl
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- more grid-containers -->
</div>
```